# Add data taken from database into new table

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("users_db");
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT subject_name FROM subject";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  ?>          

  <label for="student_subject_2">Subject 2</label>

  <select name="student_subject_2" id="student_subject_2">
      <option value="null" selected>--Select One--</option>

  <?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {      
  ?>
       <option value="<?php echo($row['subject_name']);?>"><?php echo($row['subject_name']);?></option>  
  <?php
  }
  ?>

  </select>

  <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up' align = 'center' /></td>
```

Hi,

I want to add the data from this selection into a new table in my database "users_db".

At the moment when I attempt to enter this data after I hit the submit button the message "data not entered" appears

The table "subject" at the moment contains four selections for the user

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php 
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("users_db");


     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
        $student_subject_2 = $_POST['student_subject_2'];

        $query2 = "insert into students(student_subject_2) values ('$student_subject_2')"; 

        if(mysql_query($query2))
        {

            echo  "<script>alert('data entered')</script>";

        }
        else
        {

             echo  "<script>alert('data not entered')</script>";

         }

      }
```

Comment: For a start you are missing `"` ie this `values ('$student_subject_2')` to this `values ('$student_subject_2')"`, also have a look at bind param/value
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Also I do not see any form tags, can you confirm you have both the opening and closing form tag.

Comment: yes I have both opening and closing form tags. This is just a small snippet of the overall code I didn't want to put in every single part

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query2 = "insert into students(student_subject_2) values ('$student_subject_2');
```

In this line you are missing `"` change this to

```
  $query2 = "insert into students(student_subject_2) values ('$student_subject_2');"
```

And you code is vulnerable to mysql injections

**Beware**  about `mysql_*` functions they **insecure and deprecated**. Consider using **pdo** or **mysqli_***

Comment: I have the missing " in my actual code, I just forgot to put it in here. I know about the depreciation, its just a project I started a while ago and my supervisor wants me to continue with mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your issue means that you aren't successfully running the query.  While we may be able to guess the issue with your query, it would be better for you to be able to determine the error exactly.

To troubleshoot this, you'll need to display the *error* that mysql is encountering:

```
if(mysql_query($query2)){
    echo  "<script>alert('data entered')</script>";
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
    echo  "<script>alert('data not entered.')</script>";
}
```

Additionally, you should **not** be using the mysql - library it is insecure, and is deprecated - use mysqli or pdo.

See [Choosing a Database API](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: This is a good idea. Unfortunately that snippet of code isn't working >>>>>> echo  "<script>alert('data not entered.<?php echo mysql_error(); ?>')</script>";

Comment: I see the issue - I've modified the code above to correct.

Comment: the alert just appears as "data not entered.<?php echo mysql_error()"

Comment: I put that modified code into my code, but now there is no alert shown at all?

Comment: @bano590 - I've made one more revision.  Please try it.